# How to run Js inside Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I want to add a parallax effect to a html element in my template html. I have written the code to do this, but not sure about where to implement it to run every time the page scrolls.

```
let pos = document.body.scrollTop;
document.getElementById('parallex').style.marginTop = '-' + pos + 'px';
```

I tried Adding this to the ngDoCheck function, but it worked only once. How to do it?

Comment: try on ngOnChanges

Comment: Where and How to use it?

Comment: please check this article https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I found the DoCheck function from it, but it did not help. Can you suggest one please?

Comment: try on ngOnChanges

Comment: Sorry but what should the parameter be (Simple Change Object)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186922/discussion-between-s-ruka-and-ankur-shah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Provides Host Listeners for this purpose. Best Practice is to use ViewChild to access the html element and renderer2 to update the attributes

> HTML

```
<span #parallex class="parallex">dfd</span>
```

> TS

```
@ViewChild('parallex')
el: ElementRef;

@HostListener("window:scroll")
onScroll() {
  let pos = window.pageYOffset;
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'margin-bottom', pos + "px");
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'margin-left', pos + "px");
}

constructor(
  private renderer: Renderer2
) {}
```

Checkout [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gmgn1h) for working demo.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you .

you need to use

> window.onscroll()
>   like this

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
// called when the window is scrolled.  
let pos = document.body.scrollTop;
document.getElementById('parallex').style.marginTop = '-' + pos + 'px';

}
```